# Fastest redirect on nginx for many urls?

Tags: nginx

new on nginx.

We have migrated a site and need to redirect about 800 urls to new site.

It would be faster for nginx to do it through maps, through return or some other method ?

Comment: The return would be fastest.

Comment: @IVOGELOV would it be better to use map or return for many redirects?

Comment: Would you mind showing us an example of 5 such redirects ? Return will respond either with 301 or 302 redirect. Map will simply set the value of a variable. If the new pages are on the same server - you might be able to do proxy_pass or internal URL rewrite and return the content in a single turn-around.

Comment: Actually I have to move about 800 url from the form "http://www.example.com/article/132572/content-alias" to the form "https://www.example.com/category1/content-alias". Actuall I want to change "article/articleId" part with the "categoryN". 
I could not paste you some actual url beacause of so restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly true that `map` is very fast. It is known that (quoting docs):

> Since variables are evaluated only when they are used, the mere declaration even of a large number of “map” variables does not add any extra costs to request processing.

However, in your case, you need a single variable and check it against a lot of strings. Sure it may be still fast, but it won't scale well with the more strings you have to compare. Moreover, although quite negligible, those strings have to be stored in memory.

So instead of potentially slowing down every single request, you might better off coding the redirects in your app's language.

```
server {
    # ...
    rewrite ^/article/(\d)/.* /old-format.php?article_id=$1;
    location = /old-format.php {
        internal;
        fastcgi_pass /your/php/socket;
        # all the fastcgi directives as usual
    }

    # ...
}
```

Inside the `/old-format.php`, check the `$_REQUEST['article_id']` and emit the appropriate redirect.

Why this is better:

- Pages conforming to the new URL format, won't suffer evaluation of request URI against 800 URLs; only a regular expression mismatch, which is much faster than the given map, especially so if you use `pcre_jit on;` directive atop your `nginx.conf` file
- You can (likely) write the logic of redirects in your PHP file in few lines of code (fetching relation between article and category ids from database). If speed of access of old URLs is of any concern, you can apply FastCGI cache to `old-format.php` location with things like `fastcgi_cache_valid 301 24h;` (+ define FastCGI cache zone in the `http` context)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you will need to use `map` - and if you get an error about `map_hash_bucket_size` being too small you should increase it (inside the `http` block) like this - `map_hash_bucket_size 256`

First create a file `/etc/nginx/header-maps.conf` like this:

```
map $request_uri $redirect_uri {
    /path-1      /path-1-new;
    /path-2      /path-2-new;
    /path-3      /path-3-new;
}
```

Then in `nginx.conf` or in your domain-specific config file

```
server {
    # other things here...

    # if there is a $redirect_uri set for the current URI:
    if ($redirect_uri) {
        return 301 $redirect_uri;
    }

    # other things here...
}
```

`map` is very fast - so it should not affect performance too much.

Comment: `if` is considered evil, do you have a non-if solution?

Comment: @chx Instead of using a map you can create a location block for each of the map entries - and inside each location block put an unconditional redirect to the desired path/URL. This will save you from the "evil" `if` ...